# Swift commandline tool builds in debug mode but not in release

Tags: swift, closures

I am trying to build this commandline tool: https://github.com/kindlychung/swiftsci

In debug mode it compiles fine, and the binary works as expected. But when I build in release mode, I got the following error:

```
Information:Building target 'swiftsci' from 'swiftsci' with configuration 'Release' for architecture 'x86_64' using 'OS X 10.11' sdk
Error:Build failed in 6s 446ms
Note:Write auxiliary files
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-all-target-headers.hmap
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-project-headers.hmap
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci.hmap
Note:/bin/mkdir -p /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/swiftsci-OutputFileMap.json
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-generated-files.hmap
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swift-overrides.hmap
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-own-target-headers.hmap
Note:write-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/swiftsci.LinkFileList
x86_64
Note:0  swift                    0x000000010997bfbb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
Note:1  swift                    0x000000010997c6fb SignalHandler(int) + 379
Note:2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff88ca8f1a _sigtramp + 26
Note:3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0005000200000005 _sigtramp + 1999991045
Note:4  swift                    0x0000000107d5eb29 (anonymous namespace)::SILClosureSpecializerTransform::run() + 9433
Note:5  swift                    0x0000000107cd8d99 swift::SILPassManager::runOneIteration() + 1689
Note:6  swift                    0x0000000107cd73cb swift::runSILOptimizationPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 651
Note:7  swift                    0x0000000107a6cb16 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 11830
Note:8  swift                    0x0000000107a69ad3 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2691
Note:9  swift                    0x0000000107a66154 main + 2324
Note:10 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff86ce15c9 start + 1
Note:Stack dump:
Note:0. Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/swiftsci/main.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Extensions/String.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Docopt.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Either.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Option.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Tokens.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Command.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Pattern.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Argument.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Optional.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/Required.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/OneOrMore.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/DocoptError.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/LeafPattern.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/BranchPattern.swift /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/docopt/OptionsShortcut.swift -primary-file /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/swiftsci/sciNotation/sci.swift -target x86_64-apple-macosx10.10 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -I /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Products/Release -F /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Products/Release -g -module-cache-path /Users/kaiyin/Library/Caches/AppCode33/DerivedData/swiftsci-e581131b/ModuleCache -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/swiftsci-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Products/Release/include -Xcc -I/Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -working-directory/Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci -emit-module-doc-path /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sci~partial.swiftdoc -O -module-name swiftsci -emit-module-path /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sci~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sci.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sci.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sci.swiftdeps -o /Users/kaiyin/appcodeProjects/swiftsci/Build/Intermediates/swiftsci.build/Release/swiftsci.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sci.o
Note:1. While running SILModuleTransform "Closure Specialization".
```

Any idea about what is going on?

Judging from the last line, it seems I have done something wrong [here](https://github.com/kindlychung/swiftsci/blob/master/swiftsci/main.swift#L35-L42):

```
let funcMap = [
        "sci": {
            (s: String) throws -> String in try s.sci()
        },
        "ibook": {
            (s: String) throws -> String in try s.ibook()
        }
]
```

I am not sure why this is not ok, but I tried to hack around a bit:

```
func fSci(s: String) throws -> String {
    return try s.sci()
}
func fIbook(s: String) throws -> String {
    return try s.ibook()
}

let funcMap = [ "sci": fSci, "ibook": fIbook ]
```

And I still get the same error. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler crashed, due to a segmentation fault. That means the compiler's broken in this case. You should report the bug to Apple, probably via [the swift.org bug tracker](https://bugs.swift.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa). It's not a Swift problem exactly, it's a bug in the toolchain.

The error messages suggest that the problem is due to a closure somewhere, but they don't say which one. There's really nothing in the error message that points to the closure you're looking at instead of some other one (if you look at the last line you'll see that every Swift file in the project is listed). The closure is syntactically valid (otherwise the compiler would have complained earlier instead of crashing) but something about it is getting the compiler seriously off the rails.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround, which I don't particularly like, is to disable whole module optimization by opting instead for single-file optimization:

[image]